# Java Google plus async api request

Tags: java, google-plus

I am trying to implement google plus search api solution. The functionality is following:

1. User registering on the website.
2. User is providing list of keywords he would like to receive information about.
3. Java deamon accepting those keywords and creating http requests to google plus API endpoint.

I created a code, which is doing that, but now I realised that in order to speed up requests handling(say for thousands of users) I will need to follow async requests pattern. The problem is - I do not really know how to do that. Tried to find any information on the WEB, but I cannot find anything specific to google plus java library. It might be possible that I need to create a specific HTTP Transport object, but I do not have any idea which in particular. I am not pro in Java, so any help would be greatly appreciated...

Current code:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.plus.Plus;
import com.google.api.services.plus.PlusRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.plus.model.ActivityFeed;
import com.google.api.services.plus.model.Activity;
import com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport;


HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setApplicationName("xxx")
        .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new PlusRequestInitializer("xxx")).build();

ActivityFeed activities = plus.activities().search(dataList.get(1).toString())
                            .setPageToken(lastToken)
                            .setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS_PER_REQUEST)
                            .setQuotaUser(Integer.toString(userId))
                            .execute();
List<Activity> activitiesList = activities.getItems();
```

I am using official google plus java library https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java

Thanks